# increase space between delimiter and adjacent column in matrix

Tags: formatting, matrices, horizontal-spacing

Suppose I have the following simple matrix, constructed in the usual way using `bmatrix`:

[image]

Anal-retentive editor asks if the spacing between the delimiter and the adjacent column can be increased for "aesthetic reasons". Say, perhaps yielding something like the following:

[image]

While there are a number of ways to increase spacing among rows/columns in a matrix, as much as I could find these always apply to rows with regard to other rows, columns with regard to other columns. I wasn't able to suss out how you can tweak spacing between matrix elements and the delimiters.

I came up with a kludge in the following MWE (which yielded the embedded images, above), but for MS with *lots* of matrices you might want to tweak this way, doing this 'by hand' spacing tweak is laborious, and offends the sense I work with that some clever person has a better, more general (and flexible) way. I had a quick dive into `nicematrix` (didn't see anything obvious), and thought about reverting to an `array` approach, but in the end, figured I'd see what other folks might recommend.

Thanks in advance for suggestions. [Coding suggestions only. Suggestion concerning editorial aesthetics? Well...]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
     Here is an example matrix:
     \[
     \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
       1 &  2 &  1 \\
       0 & -2 & -3 \\
       0 & 3 &  -2
     \end{bmatrix*}
    \]

Seeking a way to increase the separation between the left 
delimiter and elements of the first column, and the right 
delimiter from the right-most column The following is a 
total blunt-weapon kludge.

     \[
      \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        \ 1 &  2 &  1 \ \\
        \ 0 & -2 & -3 \ \\
        \ 0 & 3 &  -2 \
      \end{bmatrix*}
    \]

Kludge works, but is there a better way? 
[In other words, a particular package of `setting' I can 
tweak so that it auto-magically applies to bmatrix constructs?]. 

     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to redefine existing environments

```
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{<name>}{<paramters> b}{<body>}
```

In case such environment is still needed, it is also possible to make a copy

```
\NewEnvironmentCopy{<new name>}{<name>}
```

Given the information, I copied the existing `bmatrix*` to `oldbmatrix*` and then redefine it based on `matrix*`, also from [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) but with some additional spacing at brackets.

The code

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldbmatrix*}{bmatrix*}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrix*}{O{c} b}{%
  \left[\hspace{1em}\begin{matrix*}[#1]#2\end{matrix*}\hspace{1em}\right]}{}


\begin{document}
Here is an example matrix:
\[
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 &  2 &  1 \\
    0 & -2 & -3 \\
    0 & 3 &  -2
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]
Seeking a way to increase the separation between the left delimiter and elements of the first 
column, and the right delimiter from the right-most column The following is a total blunt- 
weapon kludge.

\[
  \begin{oldbmatrix*}[r]
    1 &  2 &  1 \\
    0 & -2 & -3 \\
    0 & 3 &  -2
  \end{oldbmatrix*}
\]

Kludge works but, is there a better way? [In other words, a particular package of `setting' I 
  can tweak so that it auto-magically applies to bmatrix constructs?]. 
\end{document}
```

and screenshot

[image]

Comment: Excellent -- simple, and something I can understand (meaning, I can tweak/turn on-off) as needed while not breaking anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Patch the relevant commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% patch amsmath matrix
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\env@matrix
 {\arraycolsep}% search
 {0.25\arraycolsep}% replace
 {}{\FAIL}
\xpatchcmd\endmatrix
 {\arraycolsep}% search
 {0.25\arraycolsep}% replace
 {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

% patch mathtools matrix
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\xpatchcmd\MT_matrix_begin:N
 {\arraycolsep}% search
 {0.25\arraycolsep}% replace
 {}{\FAIL}
\xpatchcmd\MT_matrix_end:
 {\arraycolsep}% search
 {0.25\arraycolsep}% replace
 {}{\FAIL}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here is an example matrix:
\[
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &  2 &  1 \\
   0 & -2 & -3 \\
   0 & 3 &  -2
 \end{bmatrix}
 \qquad
 \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
   1 &  2 &  1 \\
   0 & -2 & -3 \\
   0 & 3 &  -2
 \end{bmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Reason: both `amsmath` and `mathtools` matrices do `\hskip-\arraycolsep` at the left and at the right. With the patches, the amount of backing up is reduced by 3/4.

Comment: everybody is entitled their sense of aesthetics.

Comment: Elegant -- ultimately the most flexible way to go, but perhaps overkill for one-off immediate needs. Thanks for sharing. I learned something from working through your patches.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP has mentioned `nicematrix`, I give a solution with `nicematrix`. However, it's probably overkilling the problem (except if `nicematrix` is used for other features provided by that package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{margin=5pt,renew-matrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Excellent -- apparently I completely missed the margin argument when browsing through the nicematrix documentation. Many thanks.